# Code reuse with LESS

Tags: css, inheritance, less, reusability

So, I'm in this project. We have a running application that is the same for all the clients we have. The only thing that changes, is a little bit of (pure) CSS. The big problem, is that for each page, we have a CSS stylesheet, and for each client, we have that same sheet, with the specific changes made.

I'm thinking on a way to reduce that redundant code, and starting to use a CSS precompiler at the same time, to ease our development process, like LESS. But we have some ground rules, which are:

- Code refactoring is a bad idea, it's too many code and it is just not worth it
- The final CSS filesize cannot get bigger, our sites have really heavy traffic

My first idea, was to write a precompiler that enables "extending" sheets, like extending a view, with blocks and stuff ([like this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views)), and then write a little script that diffs the files and automatically extends it, and creates a file with the differences only, like this:

```
/** @extends: site/Home/Test */

#square-test {
    background: #C00;
}
```

But it just seems to complicated, and a little bit messy. Does anybody has been into the same situation? How did you guys handle it? Does anyone has another ideas?

I'm really thankful for your help.

EDIT:

I'm using regular LAMP, PHP 5.3.newer.

Comment: If you will be working in and growing this code base for some time to come then I would argue that refactoring is a great idea. Just because it's daunting doesn't mean it shouldn't be done. Refactoring your code is one of the best investments you can make to hedge against technical debt.

Comment: What's your server side environment? If you're using ASP.NET you may consider to use a T4 text processor (but you'll find implementations for many languages).

Comment: @PaulSasik, let's say that I get the "yes" to code refactoring. How would you do that?

Comment: I'm not a LAMP guy but, get the best refactoring tools you can get your hands on. You can do it manually with search/search and replace etc. Although, are you asking about refactoring your problem specifically or more general in LAMP technologies? Look here for some tool ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758 and here for a specific example: http://devzone.zend.com/1067/refactoring-php-code/

Comment: @PaulSasik, I mean the specific CSS problem. We have a complete application rewrite planned, probably starting mid-2014. In the mean time, I'd like to help my developers, by having less code to work on.

Comment: Could start by create a basic reuseable style sheet in LESS / CSS that can be used on any page. Then slowly update the markup on each page to use the new classes and migrate away from the CSS file per page. Like to organise my CSS like this. Found this article useful although not related to re-factoring http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/

Comment: @Adriano, that is basically what I already have, with some interesting differences. Altought I will definitely look deeper into the T4 tp, what I really want is a way to "reuse" my css code, preferably with some preprocessor, like LESS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sass to extend or import a stylesheet easily and then you can create a settings sass document that has variables such as colors, buttons styles, or whatever variations you need.

```
@import "settings"; //site specific settings
@import "allsites"; //styles for all sites
//any site specific rules here
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

This is the way that most front-end frameworks work. They have rules that work for everything then settings so that they are easily adjustable.